# how to declare a double array in javascript for this particular UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Hi i am making an UI that is given in this link [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gkjWUnMUyER6dAbTcfms?p=preview%5C)

i have a resourceType in json file which have different number of array inside it.I have to get it from the json and pass it to the function span1 so i could add it to span where it will pop up as table.Right now i am getting only one value using one D-array.can you please help me

```js
"details": [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "AOB",
  "width": "10",
  "color1": "#FF3300",
  "ResourceType": [{
    "types": "Ground services",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "1",
    "skills": "wing walker"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "CC",
  "width": "20",
  "color1": "#FF3300",
  "ResourceType": [{
    "types": "cleaner",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "20",
    "skills": "cabin cleaning"
  }, {
    "types": "cleaner",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "2",
    "skills": "trash collector"
  }, {
    "types": "supervisor",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "1",
    "skills": "cabin cleaning"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "MB",
  "width": "50",
  "color1": "#00FFFF",
  "ResourceType": [{
    "types": "engineer",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "1",
    "skills": "B1"
  }, {
    "types": "mechanic",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "2",
    "skills": "B1"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "TS",
  "width": "100",
  "color1": "#00FFFF",
  "ResourceType": [{
    "types": "groundservices",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "1",
    "skills": "drivers"
  }, {
    "types": "Toilet Truck",
    "category": "vehicle",
    "count": "1"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "WS",
  "width": "80",
  "color1": "#00FFFF",
  "ResourceType": [{
    "types": "ground services",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "1",
    "skills": "drivers"
  }, {
    "types": "Water Truck",
    "category": "vehicle",
    "count": "1"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "R",
  "width": "60",
  "color1": "#00FFFF",
  "ResourceType": [{
    "types": "ground services",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "1",
    "skills": "refuelling"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "name": "AOB",
  "width": "50",
  "color1": "#66FF66",
  "ResourceType": [{
    "types": "ground services",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "1",
    "skills": "wing walker"
  }]
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "name": "PB",
  "width": "20",
  "color1": "#66FF66",
  "ResourceType": [{
    "types": "ground services",
    "category": "employee",
    "count": "1",
    "skills": "driver"
  }, {
    "types": "tow tractor",
    "category": "vehicle",
    "count": "1"
  }, {
    "types": "ground services",
    "category": "equipment",
    "count": "1"
  }]
}]
```

the resource type is shown in this json

```js
function span1(left1,width,id,color11,name,types,category,count,skills){

    
    
      id  = "c" +id  ;
 
 var k=width;
 
 var s="<span class='" + id + "'style='border: 1px Solid Black;position:absolute;height:25px;left:" + left1 + "px;background-color:" + color11 + ";width:" + k + "px'>" + name + "<div class='tooltip'><table id='jumble'><tbody><tr><th>Resource Type</th><th>Resource Category</th><th>Resources</th><th>Skills</th></tr> <tr><td>"+ types + "</td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" + count +"</td><td>" +skills +"</td></tr></tbody></table></div></span>";
 s = s + "<div style='border-color:white;height:5px;'></div>";
 return s;
}
```

my span1 function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `ResourceType` in following way -

```
for(var i = 0; i < details.length; i++)
{
   var resourceArray = details[i].ResourceType;

   // since ResourceType is an array as well you can have following - 
   if(resourceArray && resourceArray.length > 0)
   {
      for(var j = 0; j < resourceArray.length; j++)
      {
        // following contains the data you want
        var resourceData = resourceArray[j];
        // since resourceData is an object you can access with . notation 
         // call your span1 function here 
        span1(left1,details[i].width, details[i].id,details[i].color11,details[i].name,resourceData.types,resourceData.category,resourceData.count,resourceData.skills);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i have to store every data inside resource type in diffrent variable and pass it into span1 function

Comment: I dint get your question... you want to extract the data from `resourceType` and then pass it to a `span1` function... ??

Comment: yes actually in span1 function i am passing those values inside  a div

Comment: i added the function in question

Comment: it still not working as i have outer loops also which is not able top process this code can you please be kind and take a look at plunker code

Comment: in plunker your `span1` only receives following items - `left1,width,id,color11,name` ... ?